# An integral whose upper integration limit depends on the integration variable

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

I have to compute this integrale :
$\displaystyle \int_{t}^{u} \exp(-a(u-s)) \, \mathrm{d}u$ .
The upper integrale limit depends on the integration variable so, I don't know how to do it.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: Writing $\int_\cdot^u\cdot\,du$ is bad notation anyway.

Comment: Just pretend the upper limit is a different variable. Indeed this is poor notation, but is not that uncommon to find this kind of expression.

Answer (score 1):

In that form the integral doesn't make sense, let consider instead a different notation with another variable $U$ for the integration

$$\displaystyle \int_{t}^{u} \exp(-a(U-s)) \, \mathrm{d}U$$